# How to copy only one date column from one table to another

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to `INSERT INTO` a table using the input from another table. For example:
`Table A` contains item and item description details but it has only till December 2021.
`Table B` contains date values.

I need to copy only the date column from `Table B` to `Table A` and item details can be null for future dates.

I'm using the below format to insert the data

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE A
                  ( DATE
                  , CL 1
                  , CL 2
                  , CL 3
                  , CL 4
                  , CL 5)
```

---

```
SELECT date , 0,0,0,0,0
FROM TABLE B;
```

Expectation: Need to copy the date column from table B to table A for specific date range ie. between SYSDATE and APRIL 2023
As there is no primary key we cannot join these two tables.

Please suggest for a solution to copy the future dates from `TABLE B` to `TABLE A` without using the join .

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a `WHERE` clause here:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE A ("DATE", CL1, CL2, CL3, CL4, CL5)
SELECT "date", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
FROM TABLE B
WHERE "date" >= SYSDATE AND "date" < date '2023-05-01';
```

Comment: Thank you for your response . 
In this case , the date we are referring is from different table for specific time range.
Only the zero values we are copying from Table B.
For example :  INSERT INTO TABLE A ("DATE", CL1, CL2, CL3, CL4, CL5)
SELECT "(date from TABLE X)", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
FROM TABLE B

Comment: Menon, I'd suggest you to edit the original question you posted and provide **sample data** - what you have, and what you'd want to get as a result. The way you described it so far is not understandable (at least, not to me. According to your comment, Tim didn't get it either).